# Yugabyte Backup Completed with Error but Backup is completed

Tags: yugabytedb

Hi I am getting error below when I triggered Yugabyte Backup in parallel. I also see the backup marked as completed with location where it is stored. Does this mean backup task failed in UI but the backup succeeded?

> Failed to execute task java.util.concurrent.FutureTask@2e4aaa7d, hit
> error java.lang.RuntimeException:
> UniverseUpdateSucceeded(d0b90430-25e2-4d92-954a-99eeddc875ea) failed
> with exception UserUniverse d0b90430-25e2-4d92-954a-99eeddc875ea is
> not being edited.